# Import External Data

Tags: python, external

I am trying to make a live sports score screen, but to do this I need to import data from the web to see the score. Is there any way to program this?

May somebody please create a new tag called "data"?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json()
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```